# PagerSlidingTabStrip implement

Tags: android

I am trying to do implement this library:https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

I am following sample I have this code:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return RandomsFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

And this is the fragment side:

```
public static RandomsFragment newInstance(int position) {
    RandomsFragment f = new RandomsFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}
```

I am getting following errors:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from RandomsFragment to Fragment
The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)
```

But they are used in sample you can check:

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample/MainActivity.java  (Bottom line)

And this is the fragment:

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample/SuperAwesomeCardFragment.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RandomsFragment` needs to extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, not `android.app.Fragment`.

This is because `FragmentPagerAdapter` only works with the support `Fragment` class, not the framework's `Fragment` class.

Comment: Did you also import the correct (support) `Fragment` class in your adapter?

Comment: That is correct for the fragment, but the adapter also needs to use the correct Fragment class

Comment: Yes,It worked now.But my app is crashing I know this place is not good for another question but may be you know.http://prntscr.com/4se7e4 Do you know what can be cause to this ?

Comment: I would ask a new question. Be sure to look through the exception and post all of the code relevant to the crash.

Answer (score 0):

check your imports make sure you've imported `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`